# Uploading a downloaded Image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload

I am not sure if this is even conceptually possible, but I am looking at options to upload an image that was downloaded from another site. E.g. use the Facebook API to select an image, then upload it to my site (which accepts submitted images).

I know one option is to convert an image to a Base64 String and then submit it, but as far as I know, the size of the image is a limitation. Also, the client struggles with larger images.

The caveat is of course to only use JavaScript, no Flash or ActiveX. When I say JavaScript, I of course include JavaScript libraries.

Comment: You can [read file as Binary in HTML5](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-reading-files), you can also [slice it](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/#toc-slicing-files) before uploading.

Comment: In [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/6Njtu/), I grabbed the image in binary with XHR2, then I converted it back and put it in `<img>`. You can just send the Blob data to your server.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about slicing. I will take a look at that option, though I still think I might need to do something extra (e.g. worker thread) to avoid the UI from being frozen on large files.

Comment: I won't be able to try this out in a few hours, in the meantime, the "binary file" concept applies to files, right? Can I treat a downloaded "Image" as a "File"?

Comment: Actually in my example I fetched the image as a "file" and interpret it as a [blob object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Blob). It is not like creating a dataURI (base64) from an `img` tag or `canvas`.

Comment: And then you can just upload or slice it before [uploading the blob object using XHR2](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/#toc-send-blob).